# Limiting the number of Gravity Forms submissions based on Datepicker

Tags: forms, datepicker, duplicates

Okay, so I have a snippet of code given to me from the Gravity Forms support people that is supposed to limit the amount of times a person can submit a form with a selected date. It essentially limits the duplicates in the datepicker field. Thing is, it isn't working.

Here it is:

```
/ custom no duplicates validation for form 1 field 2
add_action( 'gform_is_duplicate_1', 'limit_dates', 10, 4 );
function limit_dates( $count, $form_id, $field, $value ) {
    if ( $field['id'] == 2 && $count < 6 ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $count;
    }
}
```

It is not working. I wanted only 6 submissions for each day selected on the datepicker.

Comment: What did the Gravity Forms support people say about it not working?

Comment: Something along the lines of, the supplied code is the limit to the amount of support we can offer you here. You might consider working with a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been meaning to add support for limiting by field value to my [Better Submission Limit](http://gravitywiz.com/better-limit-submission-per-time-period-by-user-or-ip/) snippet. After you've installed the snippet, you can use this configuration to limit a field to 6 "duplicate" submissions. After that, it'll give you a validation error.

```
new GW_Submission_Limit( array(
    'form_id' => 1,
    'limit_by' => 'field_value',
    'limit' => array(
        // "2" is your field ID, "6" is your limit
        2 => 6 
    ),
    // assuming you want this limit to apply forever
    'time_period' => false 
) );
```

Full details: http://gravitywiz.com/better-limit-submission-per-time-period-by-user-or-ip/

Comment: Hi there, it is giving me the error that GW_Submission_limit is an invalid class or something. Not found. I copied and pasted the code above right into my functions.php and now the site is down. Did I do something wrong? Fatal error: Class 'GW_Submission_Limit' not found in /home/content/20/11764420/html/wp-content/themes/triton-lite/functions.php on line 6

Comment: You have to include the full snippet, not just the configuration portion.